# How to use data from one object in a scope?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state called `home.test`. In this state I inject the template `_movie-info.html` into a view.

```
.state('home.test',{
  params: {
    value: null
  },
  url: '',
  views: {
    "test":{
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_movie-info.html',
      controller: function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
        $scope.movie = $stateParams.value
        console.log ($scope.movie)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I create a scope called `$scope.movie` in the view controller and insert the value that's been passed from the `ui-sref` action. When I enter the `home.test` state the console log shows,

```
{"id":7,"title":"Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice","release_date":"2016-03-24","image":"/eJrlh2g9UGAd7R6mQAOQIIs329H.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-07T15:17:47.287Z","updated_at":"2015-12-07T15:17:47.287Z","movie_id":"209112","imdb_rating":"N/A","backdrop":"/4YxoxVGu93ta0H4u0B98niGIUAu.jpg"}
```

But when I try to use the data it doesn't work. Is this because I take the `value` of the object and insert it into the `$scope.movie`?

```
movie title: {{ movie.title }}
```

Because if I create a model for my scope like so,

```
$scope.movie = {title: 'something cool'}
```

And console log that it shows up like this,

```
Object {title: "something cool"}
```

And the `{{ movie.title }}` works.

*** EDIT ***

I suspect the problem is how `$stateParams` returns the data. If I use `$stateParams.value` it returns a string.  If I just use `$scope.movie = $stateParams` it returns an object, but it's looking weird,

```
Object{
  value: "{"id":7,"title":"Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justic…A","backdrop":"/4YxoxVGu93ta0H4u0B98niGIUAu.jpg"}"
}
value: "{"id":7,"title":"Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice","release_date":"2016-03-24","image":"/eJrlh2g9UGAd7R6mQAOQIIs329H.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-07T15:17:47.287Z","updated_at":"2015-12-07T15:17:47.287Z","movie_id":"209112","imdb_rating":"N/A","backdrop":"/4YxoxVGu93ta0H4u0B98niGIUAu.jpg"}"
```

Comment: Where are you trying to use the data?

Comment: I am trying to use the data on the `_movie-info.html` template. The problem here is how the object gets returned through the `$stateParams`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed in your edit - the data `$stateParams.value` is of type `string` - So change your code in your controller to:

```
$scope.movie = JSON.parse($stateParams.value);
```

and verify that the console output also says 'Object'

Comment: Excellent, thought there was a trick to convert it to a object.